# exclude single quote in preg_match php

Tags: php

This function should validate a valid email and should exclude an email with single quote.

```
 function _validate_email($email) {
     if (!preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,9}$/ix", trim($email))) {
            return FALSE;
        }

    return TRUE;
}
```

what should be the pattern to exclude single quotes?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'd note that `filter_var` permits an email with a single quote (`filter_var("foo'bar@example.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`). I'm presuming that's valid in an email address, but OP *may* have special requirements for some reason.

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks for pointing `filter_var`, but it needs to be strict in validating emails that's why preg_match was used in this scenario

Comment: What about `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && strpos($email, "'") === FALSE`?

Comment: Please define what "strict" means.

Comment: it should only accepts +_-' before @, but thank you. I think i got it @AlexHowansky

Comment: This is a poor way to validate emails. For example, you're allowing invalid addresses with more than 64 chars in the local part, and rejecting valid addresses with more than 9 chars in the TLD.

Comment: good point @AlexHowansky i'll use the filter_var as you've suggested but i got the answer for my question. thanks for the feedback! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got by editing the function below:

```
function _validate_email($email) {
     if (!preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-\']+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-\']+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,9}$/ix", trim($email))) {
            return FALSE;
        }

    return TRUE;
}
```